# php: generate random string on android browser

Tags: php, android

I have searched a lot about this issue, but I got nothing.
I used `str_shuffle()` to get a random string. It works fine on my laptop, **But** on my android device did not. It generate a random string, but when I refresh the page, it gives me the same string as before. **Also** when I open the page on laptop, it gives me a new string. **But** if i open the page on my phone, it gives me the same string that shown on the laptop.
 Is it a server issue? or android issue?
**Any Idea?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a browser cache related problem. Try to inlcude

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
```

in your code and retry.